# How do I use Typecript to create a generic API SDK where the return type is determined by a string literal passed in as an arguments?

Tags: typescript

If I have a preset map of string to object types, can I use that somehow to determine a) what the return value will be and b) ensure the implemented function itself is as type-safe as it can get?

Consider the following

```js
import Axios from "axios";

export const axios = Axios.create();

type Foo = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    foo: number;
}

type Bar = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    bar: number;
}

type FooResponse = {
  response: Foo[];
}

type BarResponse = {
  response: Bar[];
}

type FooBarMap = {
  foo: FooResponse;
  bar: BarResponse;
}


const getFooBar = async <T extends keyof FooBarMap>(endpoint: T, query: Record<string, any> = {}) => {
  const records: FooBarMap[T]["response"] = [];

  const response = await axios.get<FooBarMap[T]>(`/${endpoint}`, query);

  const data = response.data.response;

  records.push(...data);

  return records;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAQQB7AgZzgMyhEcBEAhiuvgNwCwAUNQKZKSxwDGEAdmvMahgLyIk0AOmZRahGLQAUASko0qMAJ5hacAGIQIcfgG9qcQ3GAATAFxxOUYGwDm8o3DaEQtC1Zv2DRzFotsAVxAAI1ooeQBfamplVTgAIUIoHTh9KkdTdxhrOwcjZ1csnK90o2Ck-yDQ8OoohVi1TQgAJVo0SA41PW8xdvY0Nw0tAG0AXUjoxRU1RKhWvs6UtMNejoGLWbGJ%20umhiFmAWUIwJe9fCAsm%20bXaPPKoDaTr-tvaydYOeFtaGCbZlMIaCUbGYcAAPAAVOD0SRsEwYADWtCUEEwe0OxwAfFJaHDIDYYBYIQAaOAARwCYSUFlarCgJjBHjspMIbCUmKWERkOg5yxY-XgYjp8MuWgxYGGENGw3wqxe%20FGKS2k0MH04cDli34hAA7oRgFxBEJvjAwX8kkcJVLsQADAD0ABJdLiTPi2DAIjbSRSqXIVfzPnATBJCClNQMhMGYIQhOHXgoVrRhcIwAE0AALKRCbNRwh%20hMan4BKBsQvJyJAA)

gives the error

> Argument of type 'Foo | Bar' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Foo & Bar'.
> Type 'Foo' is not assignable to type 'Foo & Bar'.
> Property 'bar' is missing in type 'Foo' but required in type 'Bar'.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mM7Z1w) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is unable to handle the "correlated union types" described in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), however, there is a suggested refactor described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).

First, we will need to create the following type:

```
type TypeMap = {
  foo: Foo
  bar: Bar
}
```

Now, we will refactor `FooBarMap` to be a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) that optionally accepts the key of `TypeMap` as a generic parameter, which is defaulted to all of the keys of `TypeMap` and returns the response for the given key :

```
type FooBarMap<T extends keyof TypeMap = keyof TypeMap> = {
  [K in T]: { response: TypeMap[K][] }
}[T]
```

Lastly, we will refactor the usage of passed generic in `getFooBar`:

```
const getFooBar = async <T extends keyof TypeMap>(
  endpoint: T,
  query: Record<string, any> = {},
) => {
  const records: FooBarMap<T>['response'] = [];

  const response = await axios.get<FooBarMap<T>>(`/${endpoint}`, query);

  const data: FooBarMap<T>['response'] = response.data.response;

  records.push(...data); // no error

  return records;
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAQQB7AgZzgMyhEcDkAhiuvgNwBQFApkpLHAMYQB2a8xqGAvIiWgDpGUaoRjUAFAEpKFGAE8w1OADEIEOLwDeFOHGAATAFxx2UYCwDmlPS0IhqJsxeu6s6kywCuIAEbUoSgBfWQUlOAAhQihNOB09QycYcysbODsHJJTXPV9ozx9-QIoQqjDlABVFagBZQjBY+PcIEzUINzyoEyioErLq1XUeurAAHgq4WnEWAwwAa2p5CEw4KqUR2IWllbXa+oA+RrcAbQBpfRZVgF0TLTgRNEg2R1XqkbOr46u4IJLjiquVGYbHglmoMDaPVihDQ8hYjDg40mSGmszgW2Wr3WBwkbmoM0gFhgJgqABo3ABHLwBeQmABK1GYUAMo2cVlJcEILHkh20QXJUk0hyawPY90Z0FmrSG0RG432x3wDyeaGo+G+vC+sj0ovgytYquhAHdCMAOPwBGCYKNIbL6vL9hIAAYAegAJFp8QZCSwYEEnRyqTSZFQdQb4AYxIRpRBhvaKgqldRHga1RrxSnngJIzBCAJ9c9teKmbMBGAvGgABYSAS1nOEENuEQwLxQS4iEtoYKUIA)